# Actions of cofibrations and induced maps of cofibres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cofibrations

Working in some nice category of based topological spaces (compactly generated with CW homotopy type, say) suppose we have a homotopy commutative diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 & & j & & \newline
 & A & \to & X & \newline
f & \downarrow & & \downarrow & g \newline
 & A' & \to & X' & \newline
 & & j' & & 
\end{array}
$$
whose horizontal maps are cofibrations. Any homotopy $H$ witnessing commutativity induces a map of homotopy cofibres $g_H: C\to C'$. It is my understanding that a different homotopy $K$ may produce a non-homotopic induced map $g_K$.

My question is about how the homotopy class of these "whisker maps" is related to the coaction of the fibrations involved. Recall the cofibre $C$ of $j$ admits a coaction of $\Sigma A$ given by a map
$$
C\to C\vee \Sigma A,
$$
which in a picture of $C$ as the mapping cone corresponds to pinching the cone halfway up. This induces an action of the group $[\Sigma A,C']$ on the pointed set $[C,C']$. Namely, given maps $\xi: \Sigma A\to C'$ and $g: C\to C'$, the action of $\xi$ on $g$ is given by the composition
$$
g^\xi : C\longrightarrow C\vee\Sigma A \stackrel{g\vee \xi}{\longrightarrow} C'\vee C' \stackrel{\nabla}{\longrightarrow} C',
$$
where $\nabla$ is the fold map.

> Is it true that changing the homotopy results in a whisker map in the same orbit under the coaction? More precisely, if $H$ is a homotopy witnessing commutativity of the square and $\xi\in[\Sigma A,C']$, then there is some other homotopy $K$ witnessing commutativity such that $g_H = (g_K)^\xi$? If not, then what *is* true? And where can I read about such things?